# How to get the performance of the computer shader during mobile runtime

Tags: android, mobile, glsl, hlsl

As the title, I have tried to capture data at GPU runtime with using the following tools. But none of them have a unified standard to assess the performance of cs.

- Renderdoc
- ARM mobile studio
- Snapdragon Profiler

Comment: Why would there be a "unified standard" for this?

Comment: emmm.. I want to see the performance of cs for one frame but I didn‘t find clear data to prove the time-consuming of cs.

Comment: Well, it's going to be different depending on the specific GPU, the memory attached to the GPU, how many threads there are, how complex the shader is, and what you're doing at the same time.